# Is my cat actively trying to get hurt to win sympathy and cuddling from us humans?

Tags: cats, behavior

I frequently catch my cat sitting or lying very close to the door in the kitchen which he knows opens inwards. Quite often, the door is violently opened and smacks the poor creature, and then I always feel so sorry for him and cuddle even more than usual with him. Sometimes I give him an extra treat to say I'm sorry.

Is he doing this on purpose? It's a pretty weird cat in general, but this seems like going too far. He could get seriously hurt. I try to think about this, but he inevitably will get hit by that door if he insists on "chilling" on that spot, yet he does. It seems to me as if he is planning for that to happen. It doesn't seem reasonable that a cat would not put two and two together after so many times.

Answer (score 3):

Animals do not actively seek to get hurt. They avoid it.

It's important not to impose human standards upon pets. What may seem logical to a pet owner may not be the way the pet is thinking.

There's all sorts of air currents circulating through a kitchen from the various appliances, including ovens. Often pets will lie in kitchens near refrigerators, as they will blow out warm air from underneath.

Plus there's the added attraction of the kitchen being the place in the house when all sources of food, including the pets, originate. If the cat is fed in the kitchen this multiplies this factor.

Sleeping behind a door is comfortable and offers the cat protection. As cats are predators to some animals, they are small and become prey to other, larger animals and it's instinctual for cats to find safe places to rest.

I do not believe the cat is resting there to be hit by the door. I would recommend being mindful that the cat sits there and opening the door with more caution and less violence (as you put it). The human being has a brain that is capable of more complex logical thinking. So if you are aware the cat is often there, the onus is on the owner to take care and try not to hurt the cat when opening the door.

If you cannot remember that, perhaps consider putting a door stop behind the door to prevent it being swung fully and hitting the cat. This would provide the cat with a little triangle hidey hole behind the door.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answer that your cat wouldn’t purposely do something to get hurt. While we were on vacation our cat peed all over the front room! We did a lot a research to see if the cat was mad or what, but pretty much everything we found was that cats don’t have an emotional maturity level/emotional intelligence to be manipulative, seek vengeance, etc.

However, you may be training your cat that he gets rewards for being in that spot. Giving him extra cuddles and especially treats may in his mind trigger that location with those rewards.

The last thing that comes to mind is perhaps the cat could think you are playing. Our cat loves to rough play and we give him lots of cuddles during it, which makes him like to rough play more. I think it’s pretty typical for cats to be stealthy, hide behind things, etc. Hiding behind a door totally seems like a normal cat thing to me!